# rearranging a menu with jquery: hover event not firing on drag

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to create a page which allows you to reorder a menu using the jquery sortable function.  The menu consists of a navigation bar with the links arranged horizontally; hovering over a link will show a submenu as a dropdown, and this works as expected.  However, when dragging an item to reorder it, the hover event doesn't fire, so the submenu doesn't show, preventing you from dropping the link into the it.

I reckon this might be to do with the item which is being dragged sitting directly under the mouse and preventing other objects from getting events.  I've tried mouseover and mouseout instead of hover, but that doesn't work either.

Any ideas?

**Edit**: here's my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5C8Fy/).

Comment: Can you create a http://jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: @AlexW added a jsfiddle.. and woah, never seen that before, that's really useful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the jQuery UI `droppable` behaviour and then attach behaviour onto to `over` and `out` handlers.  See [my fork of your jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nUBwd/4/).

```
$('li', menu)
    .mouseover(function () { $('>ul', $(this)).show(); })
    .mouseout(function () { $('>ul', $(this)).hide(); })
    .droppable({
        over:function() { $('>ul', $(this)).show(); },
        out:function () { $('>ul', $(this)).hide(); }});
```